# Correct way to refer to solve an equation

Tags: mathematics

I am a mathematician and I have a question about how to say correctly in English the next preceding:

> Let x=(...)(,,,)
>   If we clear away the first parenthesis we get:
>   (...)=x/(,,,,)

The “clear away” is good for this situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have "divided through" by the second bracket. This is an aspect of "rearranging" the equation, usually done to change the subject of the equation.

Such a process would normally be described this way in school maths, but in research maths, it would probably not even be commented on. The assumption is that a professional mathematician would be able to follow the algebra without needing it each step explained to her.

Answer (score 1):

I think the term for what you are doing with the first parenthesis is "isolate". An example (very basic math) of how this word is used can be found [here](https://www.onlinemathlearning.com/isolate-the-variable.html).

For example

> x = f(x,y)*g(x,y)
>
> we can isolate f(x,y) by dividing both sides by g(x,y), which would yield
>
> f(x,y) = x/g(x,y)

If f(x,y) (the expression you isolated) is your desired answer, this would be *solving for f(x,y)* by isolating it from the other terms.

Answer (score 0):

**Suitable Phrases**

- to carry over

  > The denominator was ***carried over*** to solve the equation

`x / 2 = 3` 
 `x = 2 × 3`
`x = 6`

- to rearrange

  > The equation for velocity was ***rearranged*** to find the distance travelled given the time and velocity

`v = d/t
d = v × t`

- to make [something] the subject

  > He ***made*** *p* ***the subject*** since he knew the value of *q*.

`q = 5
q = 10 - p
p = 10 + q
p = 10 + 5 = 15`

- to change the subject

  > The answer became clear only after she ***changed the subject*** of the equation.
- to solve for [something]

  > He ***solved for*** *x* first before ***solving for*** *y* in the simultaneous equations.

Comment: I have no idea why the markup is giving me so much trouble, so please ignore the bad formatting until I can fix it on computer.